# Point angular app on subdomain to subfolder with nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, subdomain, subdirectory

I want to point sub.example.com to example.com/sub (without actually redirecting). I've achieved this with following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ ;
    root /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/sub;
}
```

The problem is, I have an Angular app on sub.example.com and it tries to load its **js** resources from the below path and fails to do so (404 Not found):

```
http://sub.example.com/sub/inline.bundle.js
http://sub.example.com/sub/vendor.bundle.js
...
```

To make a build I'm using following command:

```
ng build --base-href /sub/
```

How to resolve this? Is this Angular issue or can I fix it with nginx config? I've tried the proxy_pass but with no success.

Comment: Do you really need to specify a base href here?

Comment: I think so, at least I had to use it at the beginning when I was accessing the app through example.com/sub, its source location hasn't changed, I just  want to access it through sub.example.com now

Comment: I'd say to try without. Since you've got nginx redirections, it should not be needed anymore. Otherwise, it if still does not work after removing it, have a look at the deploy-url option

Comment: It worked! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I added an answer just to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying base-href is only needed for the router if your app is not served from the root location, e.g. http://example.com/sub

In your case, you added  nginx rules so that content can be served from a sub folder, but using a "root" location (http://sub.example.com)

So from an angular point of view, everything is like it's served from a root folder, meaning there is no need to specify base-href

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem when I was implementing internationalization of Angular application that needed to be served from different sub-directories for each language. Check [my solution on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877984/776546).

Comment: Using --base-href /sub/ argument was causing my problem.